# Q: How to know whether the triangle is valid or not by angles using switch?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

i want to use switch by i can't !!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main() {

    char op ;
    float x, y, z;

    cout << "Enter the three angles : \n "; 
    cin >> x >> y >> z;

    switch (op){
    case '+' :
        cout << x + y + z == 180;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "A triangle is Not valid !! \n ";

    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Why do you want the switch?

Comment: Because this is task in the university @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Where do you set `op`?

Comment: And what does the value of `op` have to do with whether the triangle is valid?

Comment: in char for plus operation @Barmar

Comment: It looks like you forgot to write that in your program.

Comment: I think all the code is wrong @Barmar can you tell me the idea !! 
"Write a program to check whether a triangle is valid or not, when the three angles of the triangle are entered by the user. A triangle is valid if the sum of all the three angles is equal to 180 degrees. (Using switch case)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `switch` as a replacement for `if` like this:

```
#include <math.h>

switch(static_cast<int>(round(x + y + z))) {
case 180:
    cout << "The triangle is valid\n";
    break;
default:
    cout << "The triangle is not valid\n";
    break;
}
```

I use `round()` to mitigate the problem that floating point math is approximate.

Answer (score 0):

If the assignment is to switch based on result Baramr's approach is what you want.

For completeness:
If the assignment is to switch based on op to learn fall through you'd probably use the break in a conditional and fall through to default, or go to a label if you have multiple ops.

Both fall through and explicit jumps are considered bad practice, but when you learn switch you should know they exist at the very least to debug them.

```
switch (op){
case '+' :
    if( (static_cast<int>(round(x + y + z))) == 180 ){
        cout << "The triangle is valid\n";
        break;
    }
default:
    cout << "A triangle is Not valid !! \n ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bonus validation: Check that the angle values are not negative.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; 
int main() {

    float x, y, z;

    cout << "Enter the three angles : \n "; 
    cin >> x >> y >> z;

    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || z <= 0) {
        cout << "Invalid angles" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    switch (static_cast<int>(round(x + y + z))){
        case 180:
            cout << "Valid triangle" << endl;;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "A triangle is Not valid !! \n ";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```